# Sum values of same name after looked up from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

A list of strings, that part of the string, is a key in the dictionary. I want to return values from a dictionary by the keys, then sum the values.

```
d = {"2016_05" : 665,
"2016_04" : 462,
"2015_03" : 568,
"2015_08" : 895}

for a in ['Toyota_2015_03', 'Toyota_2015_04', 'Kia_2016_01', 'Kia_2016_04', 'Kia_2016_05']:
    name, year, month = a.split('_')
    sales = d.get(year + '_' + month)

    if sales is not None:
        print (name + '_' + str(sales))
```

output:

```
Toyota_568
Kia_462
Kia_665
```

I want to sum the number by 'Kia' and 'Toyota' (i.e. some form to get Kia:1127, Toyota:568). What is the good way to proceed?

Comment: Could you explain how do you get "Kia: 1127, Toyota: 568"?

Comment: @OlvinRoght, that's where I want to go to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another dict to sum the sales. You can use `dict.get()` with default value to simulate `defaultdict`

```
all_sales = {}

for a in ['Toyota_2015_03', 'Toyota_2015_04', 'Kia_2016_01', 'Kia_2016_04', 'Kia_2016_05']:
    name, year, month = a.split('_')
    sales = d.get(year + '_' + month, 0)
    if sales: # can be removed if you don't have car types with no sales or you want to see those cars
        all_sales[name] = all_sales.get(name, 0) + sales

print(all_sales)
```

Output

```
{'Toyota': 568, 'Kia': 1127}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a dictionary to hold your output:

```
result = {}
for e in data:
    name, year_month =  e.split('_', 1)
    result[name] = result.get(name, 0) + d.get(year_month, 0)

result
```

**output:**

```
{'Toyota': 568, 'Kia': 1127}
```

if you do not want to have keys with `0` as value if `year_month` is not in variable `d` you can use:

```
result = {}
for e in data:
    name, year_month =  e.split('_', 1)
    sales = d.get(year_month, None)

    if sales is not None:
        result[name] = result.get(name, 0) + sales
```

Comment: thank you for the knowledge sharing and help on this question. it's really thoughtful. but another answer came in earlier and same direct as yours. would you mind i take it for the answer?

Comment: just fine do not worry :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
d = {"2016_05" : 665,
"2016_04" : 462,
"2015_03" : 568,
"2015_08" : 895}
new_d = {}
for a in ['Toyota_2015_03', 'Toyota_2015_04', 'Kia_2016_01', 'Kia_2016_04', 'Kia_2016_05']:
    name, year, month = a.split('_')
    sales = d.get(year + '_' + month)

    if sales is not None:
        if name in new_d:
            new_d[name] = new_d[name] + sales
        else:
            new_d[name] = sales
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict  
d = {'2016_05': 665, '2016_04': 462, '2015_03': 568, '2015_08': 895}

result = defaultdict(int)
for a in ['Toyota_2015_03', 'Toyota_2015_04', 'Kia_2016_01', 'Kia_2016_04', 'Kia_2016_05']:
    name, year_month = a.split('_', 1)    #split with maxsplit param
    sales = d.get(year_month)

    if sales is not None:
        result[name] +=sales              #Increment Count
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Toyota': 568, 'Kia': 1127})
```

Comment: Upvoted. You can avoid checking the presence of the timestamp, just add zero in such case `d.get(year_month,0)`

Comment: @Pynchia. That could \possibly give empty dict values..Ex: `{'Toyota': 568, 'Kia': 1127, 'BMW': 0}`...If OP is ok with that then using `d.get(year_month,0)` is perfect

Answer (score 1):

Try this. By using pure python dictonary.

```
>>> d = {"2016_05" : 665, "2016_04" : 462, "2015_03" : 568, "2015_08" 
    : 895}
>>> li = ['Toyota_2015_03', 'Toyota_2015_04', 'Kia_2016_01', 
   'Kia_2016_04', 'Kia_2016_05']
>>> cars = dict()
>>> for ele in li:
...     name, year, month = ele.split('_')
...     sales = year+'_'+month
...     if sales in d.keys():
...             if name in cars.keys():
...                     cars[name] += d[sales]
...             else:
...                     cars[name] = d[sales]
... 
>>> cars
{'Toyota': 568, 'Kia': 1127}
>>>
```